# Preventing an incoming VoIP call while already in VoIP Call with CallKit

Tags: callkit, pushkit

I would like to know if there is a better way than mine using Callkit, while A and B users already in a call.

A and B are already in a VoIP call with CallKit. 
C calls A or B, it doesn't matter. In this case, A or B sends busy but they don't want to show the idiot screen of CallKit.

As a workaround, I report the incoming call with the same UUID used to report the ongoing call, so that I get only error 2 from apple in the log. Is there a better way than this?

Comment: Last time I checked, while you have an ongoing CallKit call, you can receive any PushKit notification you want without reporting a new incoming call. Isn't it working anymore?

Comment: Hi @Marco, I didn't get you... you refer to the my previous question?

Comment: I mean that the last time I've tried to run a VoIP app on iOS 13, I didn't experience your issue; i.e. while a CallKit call was active, I was able to receive any PushKit notification I wanted without reporting a new incoming call.

Comment: You must report incoming call any time you receive a push with pushKit.

Comment: Since I was curious to see if something is really changed since the last time I've checked, I've tried just now with Xcode 11.3.1 and iOS 13.3 and it works as I described earlier: while I'm in conversation I can receive any PushKit notification without reporting a new incoming call, I just send the busy signal and I'm done without any error.

Comment: You mean when the app on foreground, you don't need to reportIncomingCall.. well in this case you send busy signal to Sip, but I think after a while you won't receive a push since the closure of push kit not called from report incoming call....

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/205954/discussion-between-marco-and-steven).

Comment: Thanks Marco, for now I cannot, I have a meeting after 2 mins. Thank you anyway

Comment: @Marco, however it won't work if you are app on background... A call B and they are in conversation, A app in background but still they are in conversation and C call  A in this case if you don't report incoming Call you will risk to not receive push..

Comment: Are you sure or is it only a supposition? Did you test it and experienced problems? The few tests I've done, all worked well with the app in background and foreground.

Comment: Well this completely depends between your device and server. Apple says that anytime you receive a pushKit you MUST call reportIncomingCall method, but if you are in background or in foreground and while you are in call, you will receive a call through sip and Not Pushkit that is Ok you can send busy, but if you receive first PushKit then call through Sip and you won't show the reportIncomingCall then you will have a problem...